Twitter login error on mobile application (works fine on web)
We are facing an issue with Twitter login on our mobile application (both iOS and Android), though it works completely fine on web.
Here are the errors we are getting:
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig

at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3351)
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:3285)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:3187)
at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3580)
at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1196)
at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8889)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.executeRequest(ActivityStarter.java:1131)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:897)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1721)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1571)
at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivity(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1523)
at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityTaskManager.java:1671)
at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1190)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1159)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthConfig
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)                                                                                                   

Failed to get request token
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException: Request Failure
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.b.onFailure(Callback.java:5)

Authorization completed with an error
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.a$a.a(OAuthController.java:16)
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$a.a(OAuth1aService.java:3)

Any idea on how to fix that?
We have tried adding a valid callback url "http://twitter-oauth.callback/" but that didn't help.
